# gRPC transcoding to create relation b/w HTTP and gRPC

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc-go

I am using google.api.Service type YML to define my http endpoints for gRPC calls. I want to send a 202 response code for some of my endpoints. How can I do that?

```
# see also:
# https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/grpc-service-config
# https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc-service-config/reference/rpc/google.api#service
#

type: google.api.Service
config_version: 3
title: My APP
apis:
  - name: test.com.yu

usage:
  rules:
    - selector: "*"
      allow_unregistered_calls: false

http:
  rules:
    - selector: com.v1.Greet.AddCatalog
      post: "/v1/service_instances/{instance_id}"
      body: "*"
      response:
        status:
          code: 201
```